# What happens if you repeatedly take the arithmetic mean and geometric mean?

Tags: means

Given two positive real numbers, $A$ and $B$, such that $A\leq B$, take the geometric mean, giving $A'$, and the arithmetic mean, giving $B'$. Repeat ad infinitum. My intuition tells me that, since both means give values between the two original numbers, they will converge as the number of repetitions approaches infinity. Is this correct? Is there a simple formula to determine on what value they converge?

Comment: How do you repeatedly take the means?

Answer (score 19):

Indeed, they converge to what is known as the [Arithmetic–geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean). Unfortunately there is no simple formula, but calculating it recursively, at least to a certain precision, could be considered "simple".

To see that it converges, let $a_0=A$, $b_0=0=B$ and

$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_nb_n}$$
$$b_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}$$

So that, by the AM-GM-inequality $$a_n\le a_{n+1} \le b_{n+1}\le b_n$$ for all n. And the difference $$b_n-a_n\le\frac{b_0-a_0}{2^n}$$
converges to zero. The reason this last inequality holds is that the difference clearly shrinks faster than if we in stead let $b_n$ be constant, in which case the difference would be divided by two at each step.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the response! As a follow-up, is there any practical application for the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean?

Comment: The arithmetic-geometric mean provides [an efficient way of computing elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean#Properties), and also apparently logarithms (mentioned on the same Wikipedia page further down). Additionally, see [Gauss' constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_constant). I'm sure there are more places where the concept crops up.

Comment: Cool. For some reason, the Wikipedia page isn't opening right now. I'll give it a read later.

Comment: @Malcolm, see the wonderful *Pi and the AGM*.

Answer (score 9):

This is the [arithmetic-geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean). Yes, it does converge for positive starting values. No, there is no simple formula for the mean, although there are some interesting equivalents in the form of integrals (see the link).